# VS2015 is unable to reference project dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, dependency-management, portable-class-library

I am trying to reference a class library project within the solution to a simple console application. But it seems like Visual Studio wont let me.

I have searched around, and i keep finding guides on how to add dependencies, but no-one seems to have the same issue, as the dependencies has been added to the project.

[image: Project]

If you look at the image above, you will see that this is just a plain project, brand new Console Application with a Class Library, nothing edited except the dependencies, and a extra line trying to reference Class1.cs from the Class Library.

I get a intellisense message suggesting me to add the reference to the project, if i click it, nothing happens.

As you can also see, i tried to add the using statement manually, without any success. It just says "Cannot resolve symbol ClassLibrary1"

[image: Dependency]

Image showing that i added the dependecy for the project.

[image: Project reference]

Image showing that i have tried adding the project reference

Now, All this beeing said. The same thing happens to the project i am suppose to work on, but on that project, i just get the message "Cannot add project X as a reference" when trying to add the class library as a reference. But i can add the Dependency, but still, it basically gives me the same error as this clean project does.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 - Enterprise.

```
Class Library Project.json: 
    {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library",
      "authors": [ "Tweek" ],
      "tags": [ "" ],
      "projectUrl": "",
      "licenseUrl": "",

      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": { }
      }
    }
```

ConsoleApp1 Project.json after editing as suggested in one of the answers:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleApp1 Console Application",
  "authors": [ "Tweek" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "commands": {
    "ConsoleApp1": "ConsoleApp1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem -

You have to use the "Class library" or "Class Library (portable)" under "Windows"

[image: Project]

Answer (score 1):

Your console application is targeting `DNX 4.5.1`, which is part of the new ASP.NET runtime. If you create a class library that is targeting .NET 4.5, it may not be compatible due to the new framework.

You can resolve this by creating your class library using the new `Class Library (Package)` project, which can target the new framework.

Alternatively, edit the `project.json` of your console application and remove `dnxcore50` from the `frameworks` section and add a reference to your library:

```
{
    ...
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [New Project Window Image](http://i.imgur.com/mbpUPYe.png) displays the window that comes up when i create a new solution is telling me that im using the ```Class Library (Package)``` as you mentioned. 
Its targeting .net 4.5.2, its showing DNX 4.5.1 in the window, I Removed the dnxcore50 from frameworks as you mentioned, without result. I have updated the question with the project.json files.

Comment: Two things you can try are updating the framework of your class library from `dotnet` to `dnx451`, and moving the dependency from the `dnx451` subsection to the main dependency section. I don't think either should really make a difference but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Ok, so updating the dotnet to dnx451 worked, but the same cant be said for the original problem where i have a MVC application and a Class Library (Fresh out of the box). Seems like the Web application doesnt have a reference to DNX 4.5.2/1